# How to change the white sidebar color in html email template

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, background-color

I've been trying to edit the background color of my HTML email template, but I just want to change the sidebar which is white, not the email body's background.

this is my CSS

```
 <style type="text/css"><style type="text/css">@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700');  
    
    }

      ReadMsgBody {
              width: 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass {
              width: 100%;
            }
            .ExternalClass,
            .ExternalClass p,
            .ExternalClass span,
            .ExternalClass font,
            .ExternalClass td,
            .ExternalClass b,
            .ExternalClass br,
            .ExternalClass img .ExternalClass div {
              line-height: 100%;
            }
            a:link {
              color:  #075792;
              background-color:  transparent;
              text-decoration: underline;
            }
            a:visited {
             color:  #075792;
             background-color:  transparent;
             text-decoration: underline;
      }
a:hover{
color: red;
background-color:transparent;
text-decoration: underline;
      }
            body {
              -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
              -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
              margin: 0 !important;
              padding: 0;
            }
            body,
            #body_style {
              background: #fffffe;
              min-height: 1000px;
            }
            p {
              margin: 1em 0;
            }
            table td {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              border-spacing: 0 !important;
            }
            table tr {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              border-spacing: 0 !important
            }
            table tbody {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              border-spacing: 0 !important
            }
            table {
              border-collapse: collapse;
              border-spacing: 0 !important
            }
            span.yshortcuts,
            a span.yshortcuts {
              color: #ffffff;
              background-color: none;
              border: none;
            }
            span.yshortcuts:hover,
            span.yshortcuts:active,
            span.yshortcuts:focus {
              color: #ffffff;
              background-color: none;
              border: none;
            }
            img {
              outline: 0;
              -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
            }
            a img {
              border: none;
            }
            @-ms-viewport {
              width: device-width;
            }
            a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
              color: inherit !important;
              text-decoration: none !important;
              font-size: inherit !important;
              font-family: inherit !important;
              font-weight: inherit !important;
              line-height: inherit !important;
            }
            .yahooNone {
              display: none;
            }
            .view {
              display: none;
            }
            #radio-1:checked~.container .view1,
            #radio-2:checked~.container .view2,
            #radio-3:checked~.container .view3 {
              display: block;
            }
            input {
              opacity: 0;
              position: absolute;
              display: none;
            }
            @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
              .cbox:checked+.interactive {
                display: block !important;
                max-height: none !important;
              }
              .fallback {
                display: none !important;
              }
              /*   Hide interactive portion from AOL Mail */
              input[class~="aolmail_cbox"]:checked~.interactive {
                display: none !important;
              }
              input[class~="aolmail_cbox"]:checked~.fallback {
                display: block !important;
              }
        <style type="text/css">@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
        .container,
        .stack {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .footer {
          width: auto !important;
          margin-left: 0;
        }
        .mobile-hidden,
        .noMo {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .logo {
          display: block !important;
          padding: 0 !important;
        }
        img {
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          max-height: auto !important;
        }
        .header img {
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          max-height: auto !important;
        }
        .photo img {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        .drop {
          display: block !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          float: left;
          clear: both;
        }
        .footerlogo {
          display: block !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          padding-top: 15px;
          float: left;
          clear: both;
        }
        .nav4,
        .nav5,
        .nav6 {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .tableBlock {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .responsive-td {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: block !important;
          padding: 0 !important;
        }
        .fluid,
        .fluid-centered {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        .responsive-tdbottom {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: block !important;
          text-align: center !important;
          border-bottom: 1px #d2d2d2 solid;
          padding-top: 20px !important;
          border-left: 0px solid #ffffff !important;
        }
        .responsivepadding-td {
          width: 100% !important;
          display: block !important;
          padding-top: 20 !important;
        }
        .fluid-centered {
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
            }
             /* Your custom styles here */
        .hund {
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        .wrap400 {
          width: 400px !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        .block {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .center {
          text-align: center !important;
          margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        .hero_txt01 {
          font-size: 36px !important;
          line-height: 41px !important;
        }
        .hero_txt02 {
          font-size: 14px !important;
          line-height: 24px !important;
          padding: 30px 0 34px !important;
        }
        .secondary_txt01 {
          font-size: 30px !important;
          line-height: 30px !important;
          padding: 28px 23px 8px 25px !important;
        }
        .secondary_txt02 {
          font-size: 14px !important;
          line-height: 19px !important;
          padding: 8px 23px 0px 25px !important;
        }
        .btn {
          width: 100% !important;
          font-size: 14px !important;
        }
        .w4background {
          background: url("images/hero_background01_MB.jpg");
          background-color: #0064b1;
          background-size: 400px !important;
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          width: 400px !important;
          height: 443px !important;
        }
        .w4hero_txt01 {
          font-size: 36px !important;
          line-height: 46px !important;
        }
        .w4hero_txt02 {
          font-size: 20px !important;
          line-height: 26px !important;
        }
        .w4hero_txt03 {
          font-size: 14px !important;
          line-height: 24px !important;
          padding: 30px 0 34px !important;
        }
        .w4secondary_txt01 {
          font-size: 30px !important;
          line-height: 30px !important;
          padding: 28px 23px 8px 25px !important;
        }
        .w4secondary_txt02 {
          font-size: 14px !important;
          line-height: 19px !important;
          padding: 8px 23px 0px 25px !important;
        }
        u + .body .hero_txt01 {
          /* targets gmail app only */
          font-size: 32px !important;
          line-height: 39px !important;
        }
        .leftPAD {
          padding-left: 20px !important;
        }
        .em_hide {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .em_br {
          display: block !important;
        }
        .mob-head {
          font-size: 35px !important;
          line-height: 45px;
        }
        .entry {
          padding-right: 20px;
        }
        .videoPad {
          padding: 20px !important;
        }
        .videoTxt {
          padding: 0 20px 45px !important;
        }
        .wrap90 {
          width: 90% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        .qHeight {
          height: 300px !important;
        }
        /* MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
        body {
          padding: 0px !important;
          font-size: 16px !important;
          line-height: 150% !important;
        }
        h1 {
          font-size: 22px !important;
          line-height: normal !important;
        }
        h2 {
          font-size: 20px !important;
          line-height: normal !important;
        }
        h3 {
          font-size: 18px !important;
          line-height: normal !important;
        }
        .buttonstyles {
          font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif !important;
          font-size: 16px !important;
          color: #ffffff !important;
          padding: 10px !important;
        }
        /* END OF MOBILE GLOBAL STYLES - DO NOT CHANGE */
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        .container {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
        .mobile-hidden {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .logo {
          display: block !important;
          padding: 0 !important;
        }
        .photo img {
          width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
        }
        .nav5,
        .nav6 {
          display: none !important;
        }
        .fluid,
        .fluid-centered {
          width: 100% !important;
          max-width: 100% !important;
          height: auto !important;
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
        .fluid-centered {
          margin-left: auto !important;
          margin-right: auto !important;
        }
      }
      @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
        span.entry {
          position: relative;
          padding-right: 20px !important;
          width: 100%;
          display: block;
        }
        span.entry:after {
          content: "+";
          font-size: 25px;
          color: #ffffff;
          position: absolute;
          right: 5px;
          top: 25px;
        }
        span.entry.open:after {
          content: "-";
          font-size: 28px;
          color: #ffffff;
          position: absolute;
          right: 7px;
          top: 20px;
        
    
}
      }
    </style>
    <!--[if mso]>
      <style type="text/css">
        /* Begin Outlook Font Fix */
        body,
        table,
        td {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        } /* End Outlook Font Fix */
      </style>
    <![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9
      ]><xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG /> <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml><!
    [endif]-->
    </style>
  </head>
  <body
    data-gr-ext-installed=""
    data-new-gr-c-s-check-loaded="14.1020.0"
    data-new-gr-c-s-loaded="14.1020.0"
  >
    <meta charset="us-ascii" /><meta
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
      name="viewport"
    /><meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" /><meta
      http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
      content="IE=edge"
    /><meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection" /><!--[if (mso 16)]>
      <style type="text/css">
        a {
          text-decoration: none;
        }
      </style> <!
    [endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9
      ]><style>
        sup {
          font-size: 100% !important;
        }
      </style><!
    [endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG></o:AllowPNG>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
    <![endif]-->
```

I'm trying to hide the color on the sides. my understanding is that I'll have to create blocks so the email template covers the full page instead of just the middle smaller portion of it? I don't know much regarding html/css.

Comment: show us some code example

Comment: added the css. thanks

Comment: Which bit is the 'sidebar'? Perhaps a screenshot of what want with labels will help

Answer (score 0):

bgcolor="#ffffff"
just give this code in table tag and change color code which you want to make background
in which you want to change background color. you can contact panchalbhargav1995 in gmail for more help regarding email template.

Comment: Not the best solution, in your CSS you have defined/set a background color . Looking at the code provided, the change should be in CSS and not on table. It will only double up your code.